# What is this piece of fatty thing, inside a fish (a large snapper) which was near the roe?

Tags: fish, offal

I had a quite large female snapper, it had large amount of fish roe, but nearby it was an interesting piece looking like pure piece of fat, quite hard and solid.

Here is a photo, these are the two large white things taking up most of the photo. The reddish thing in the upper-right corner is from a different fish, but I suspect its fundamentally the same kind of thing.

[image: fatty thing from a snapper, what is it?]

What is this organ called and how do you eat it?

Comment: Do you have a picture you can post?

Comment: @AMtwo yes, just added a picture.

Comment: What makes you think it's not just fat? does it melt when heated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like the ovaries.

I don't know how anyone else cooks them, but I usually prepare them with a simple Japanese recipe: simmer in a water, dashi, sake, mirin, sugar, soy sauce, ginger mix. Great companion for drinking!

A quick search and I can't find any recipes for this in English... You could search "真子" and "レシピ" to find other recipes (in Japanese). There's a few videos on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hk-f2pNPcKE) as well.

(Remember to remove the fibers and membrane and remove the blood gently, then wash with cold water/run it through hot water/lightly salt to remove the smell.)